# Java Slick scale Image without anti-aliasing

Tags: java, antialiasing, slick2d

In the Slick library (based off of LWJGL), you can scale images after you load them with `getScaledCopy`, but it will apply anti-aliasing. I want the edges to stay rough; I'm making pixel art. How can I do this?

Comment: Wild guess based on the javadocs: try using [`setFilter()`](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#setFilter(int)) to set the image filter to [`FILTER_NEAREST`](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#FILTER_NEAREST) before scaling the image.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Post this answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the comments:

The documentation implies that the [`filter` property](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#setFilter%28int%29) of `Image`s controls how images are scaled. To scale an image without smoothing, use the [nearest neighbour filter](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#FILTER_NEAREST):

```
Image original = …;
original.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
Image scaled = original.getScaledCopy();
```